# Invoke alexa skill through a request rather than a wake up word

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am new to Alexa, so please pardon me if this was a foolish question. I felt a great need of help to solve this question. The question was

I am working on a web based application where the camera constantly looks for a motion detection. If there is a change in position of an object, then alexa skill has to be launched. Generally, one has to invoke the skill saying `Alexa, open Cake Walk`, believing cake walk was a skill name. However, over here, the skill has to triggered based on motion detection.

For instance, When a person comes before the camera, the alexa skill has to be launched and respond with a voice saying "Hello, welcome to the conference."

**To conclude, my question, Is there a way to invoke a skill rather than through voice ?. If so, would you please let me know how to do it**

Comment: I think you can't open a Skill _from remote_, you have to open it with the voice. One thing you can do is send notification with [Proactive Events](https://developer.amazon.com/it/docs/smapi/proactive-events-api.html), but Echo will not speak, it'll receive a notification and the Echo led will blink in yellow.

Comment: You can use voicemonkey https://app.voicemonkey.io to invoke any alexa routine which in turn can be called via IFTTT .

Answer (score 0):

No, at this time, you can't trigger a skill.

I have the same problem.  I solved it by creating a virtual sensor device (ie implement the Alexa device APIs).  Within the Alexa configuration, tie the state change of the device to a built-in routine.  You are limited to what you can do with a built-in routine, so I mostly just use it for household broadcast messages or messages to a specific device.

For example, I have a smart switch attached to my dryer.  I don't control the switch, but monitor the current.  When it is on and falls below a specific level, I trigger the virtual sensor to on (and then back off a little while later). The Alexa routine tied to it, then plays "Dryer done" on the Echo on the far side of the house.

My wife rejected having a notification for camera movement detection.  The birds and wind created too much noise.  I will be adding, to my skill, an intent for when the last motion occurred. That way, when Alexa announces a delivery has been completed, she can check if it went to the front door or the mailbox.

Comment: If you are willing, can you share implementation of Alexa device APIs. thank you

Answer (score -3):

I recently released a skill called [Virtual Buttons](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08259XK1Z) that let's you trigger Alexa Routines (and therefore skills) via a simple REST API. One of the most common things people use it for is to announce camera motion.

Virtual Buttons is free to use unless you need more than one button (so you can trigger more than one routine). You can read more about it at [www.virtualbuttons.com](https://www.virtualbuttons.com)